# What's the Android UI design pattern Reader, HNews use?

Tags: android, user-interface

What's the design pattern called, and are there tools to make things looking like this?

[image: HNews Android app]
[image: Google Reader Android app]

Comment: Do you mean the [action bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) at the top or the `ListView` below that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the title bar, it's called [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). Action Bar is officialy supported since Android 3.0. If you want to target pre-3.0 Android versions, you can use [ActionBarSherlock library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).